# Deleting elements that equal zero in dynamic array without using secondary array in C language

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic, codeblocks

Hello everyone i want to remove null elements from a dynamyc array without using another intermidate dynaminc array , and in the final result my program should print only non null elements.
For exemple :
the input is                :[ 2 3 0 3 0 6 ]
the result output should be :[2 3 3 6]
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int *T,i,n,*p,*k;

printf("entrez the size of the array\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

T=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

for (p=T;p<T+n;p++){printf("Enter element T[%d]=",p-T);
                    scanf("%d",p);}
printf("\n");
printf("[");
printf("\t");
for (p=T;p<T+n;p++){printf("%d\t",*p);}
printf("]");

for (p=T;p<T+n;p++){
                     if(*p==0){
                               k=p;
                               for(k=p;k<T+n-1;k++){*k=*(k+1);}
                                n--;}
printf("\n");
printf("[");
printf("\t");
for (p=T;p<T+n;p++){printf("%d\t",*p);}
printf("]");
}}
```

But unfortunatly my program didn't show the result array without null elements;it stays the same .

Comment: Do format your code properly.

Comment: Note: `printf("Enter element T[%d]=",p-T)` invokes Undefined Behavior if `sizeof (a_pointer)` is not equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting this part:

```
for (p=T;p<T+n;p++)
{if(*p==0){k=p;
           for(k=p;k<T+n-1;k++){
              *k=*(k+1);}
              n--;

              }


printf("\n");
printf("[");
printf("\t");
for (p=T;p<T+n;p++)
{printf("%d\t",*p);

}
printf("]");
}}
```

The code will be like this:

```
    for (p=T;p<T+n;p++)
    {
        if(*p==0)
        {
            k=p;
            for(k=p;k<T+n-1;k++)
            {
                *k=*(k+1);
            }
            n--;
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("[");
        printf("\t");
        for (p=T;p<T+n;p++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",*p);
        }
        printf("]");
    }
}
```

Now it is clear that the printing part is inside the loop to remove elements with the value zero.

If the first element is zero, it can be removed correctly.

After the printing part, `p` will become `T+n` and it will make the outer loop end.

The printing part should be *after* the loop to remove elements with the value zero.

Also you shouldn't do `p++` when `*p==0` to avoid overlooking at zero after zero.

```
    for (p=T;p<T+n;)
    {
        if(*p==0)
        {
            k=p;
            for(k=p;k<T+n-1;k++)
            {
                *k=*(k+1);
            }
            n--;
        }
        else
        {
            p++;
        }
    }
    /* get this out of the loop */
    printf("\n");
    printf("[");
    printf("\t");
    for (p=T;p<T+n;p++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",*p);
    }
    printf("]");
}
```

Comment: your code removes null elements only if there is one in the first position but if they are in the middle or elsewhere in the array they can't be removed and nothing happen

Comment: @smailys [My code looks working](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9uKQA74uuSw4AcUj). Did you compile new code and executed correct program?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking in the right direction, the biggest problem is you fail to validate anything and you want to only increment `p` in your insert loop after an integer is provided by the user. You can also initialize both `p` and `k` as you enter your removal loop, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* simple function to empty stdin after matching-failure */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void)
{
    int *T, n, *p, *k;

    puts ("entrez the size of the array");
    if (scanf ("%d",&n) != 1) {                        /* validate EVERY input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    T = malloc (n * sizeof *T);
    if (T == NULL) {                                   /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-T");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (p = T; p < T + n;) {   /* only increment on valid inut */
        printf ("Enter element T[%ld] = ", p - T);
        if (scanf ("%d",p) != 1) {                      /* validate EVERY input */
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();                              /* remove non-digits */
            continue;                                   /* try again */
        }
        p++;                                            /* now increment pointer */
    }
    
    fputs ("\n[", stdout);                              /* no multiple printf req'd */
    for (p = T; p < T+n; p++)
        printf (" %3d", *p);
    puts (" ]");
    
    for (p = T, k = T; p < T + n; p++) {                /* initialize both p and k */
        if (*p != 0)
            *k++ = *p;              /* assign and increment k only when p not zero */
    }
    n = k - T;                      /* only reset n after loop completes */
    
    fputs ("[", stdout);
    for (p = T; p < T+n; p++)
        printf (" %3d", *p);
    puts (" ]");

    free (T);                       /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

**Example Use/Output**

Invalid input is intentional. If your code will not handle an invalid input, you are inviting undefined behavior, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/array_rm_nul
entrez the size of the array
6
Enter element T[0] = 2
Enter element T[1] = 3
Enter element T[2] = bananas
  error: invalid integer input.
Enter element T[2] = 0
Enter element T[3] = 3
Enter element T[4] = 0
Enter element T[5] = 6

[   2   3   0   3   0   6 ]
[   2   3   3   6 ]
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH IT WORKED FINE

Comment: One remark ; the part of your code that is important for me it was

Comment: `for (p = T, k = T; p < T + n; p++) {`
        `if (*p != 0)`
        `*k++ = *p;`             
    `}`
    `n = k - T; `

Comment: YOU REALLY SAVED MY LIFE THANKS  MILLIONS TIME

Comment: You are very welcome. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems with your loops that removes zeroes.

The first one is that after the inner loop

```
for(k=p;k<T+n-1;k++){*k=*(k+1);
```

the pointer p now points to an unprocessed element )next after the removed element) of the array.

However in the outer loop the pointer p is incremented

```
for (p=T;p<T+n;p++){
               ^^^
```

Thus the unprocessed element is skipped.

The second problem is that it is inefficient always to copy all elements of the array after removing the current element equal to 0.

Always try to write a more general code.

You could define a function that "removes" a specified value from an array.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 size_t remove_item( int *a, size_t n, int item )
 {
    int *p = a;
    
    for ( int *q = a; q != a + n; ++q )
    {
        if ( *q != item )
        {
            if ( p != q )
            {
                *p = *q;
            }
            ++p;
        }
    }
    
    return ( size_t )( p - a );
 }
 
int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = {  2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 6 };
    size_t n = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    n = remove_item( a, n, 0 );
    
    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *p );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 3 3 6
```

The function returns the number of actual elements in an array after removing elements with the specified value.

If the passed array was allocated dynamically then you could reallocate it after calling the function like for example

```
int *tmp = realloc( T, n * sizeof( int ) );
if ( tmp != NULL ) T = tmp;
```

Pay attention to that you should free the allocated memory for the array when it is not required any more.